# Manipulating dict values in Bigquery

Tags: string, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

I have a bigquery table column with data like

[{"start_time":"06:00AM","end_time":"11:59PM","start_day":"SUNDAY","end_day":"SUNDAY"},{"start_time":"06:00AM","end_time":"11:59PM","start_day":"MONDAY","end_day":"MONDAY"}]

I would like to reorder the above as

[{"start_day":"SUNDAY","end_day":"SUNDAY","start_time":"06:00AM","end_time":"11:59PM"},{"start_day":"MONDAY","end_day":"MONDAY","start_time":"06:00AM","end_time":"11:59PM"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible way:

```
WITH
  jdata AS (
  SELECT
    "[{\"start_time\":\"06:00AM\",\"end_time\":\"11:59PM\",\"start_day\":\"SUNDAY\",\"end_day\":\"SUNDAY\"},{\"start_time\":\"06:00AM\",\"end_time\":\"11:59PM\",\"start_day\":\"MONDAY\",\"end_day\":\"MONDAY\"}]" AS json_string)
SELECT
  TO_JSON_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(t))
FROM (
  SELECT
    JSON_QUERY(array_elements,
      '$.start_day') AS start_day,
    JSON_QUERY(array_elements,
      '$.end_day') AS end_day,
    JSON_QUERY(array_elements,
      '$.start_time') AS start_time,
    JSON_QUERY(array_elements,
      '$.end_time') AS end_time
  FROM
    jdata j,
    UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(j.json_string)) array_elements) AS t
```

Not a very pretty way, sorry..

EDIT:

In your case you will need to change the FROM statement by replacing "jdata" with your table address (something like `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`), and "j.json_string" by  "j.[column name of the JSON string]"

Comment: How do i get the first part of the query...I don't want to hard code values like [{\"start_time\":\"06:00AM\",\"end_time\":\"11:59PM\",\"start_day\":\"SUNDAY\",\"end_day\":\"SUNDAY\"},{\"start_time\":\"06:00AM\",\"end_time\":\"11:59PM\",\"start_day\":\"MONDAY\",\"end_day\":\"MONDAY\"}]" AS json_string)

How do I achieve it without hard coding?

Comment: Oh you don't have to. That part was for reproducing your data. In your case you just need to modify the FROM statement.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: What does $[0] give? When i use this query the result is null

Comment: $[0] gives you the element 0 of your JSON array. In your case the element about SUNDAY