# Reorder the values in array containing strings in Bigquery

Tags: arrays, string, google-bigquery

I have a bigquery column "JSON" which is of JSON type. The column data looks something like below

```
"{
""placement"": {
    ""daypart_targeting"": {
        ""part"": [
            {
                ""start_time"": ""06:00AM"",
                ""end_time"": ""11:59PM"",
                ""start_day"": ""SUNDAY"",
                ""end_day"": ""SUNDAY""
            },
            {
                ""start_time"": ""06:00AM"",
                ""end_time"": ""11:59PM"",
                ""start_day"": ""MONDAY""   ,
                ""end_day"": ""MONDAY""
            }
        ]
    },
    ""industry"": null,
}
```

}"

I have tried a query like below:
select
PlacementID,
split(replace(replace(regexp_replace(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON, '$.placement.daypart_targeting.part'), ',"end_day":[^/{]*', ''), '"', ''), '[{', ''), '{') as time from project.dataset.table

The output is:

```
Row PlacementID daypart 
1   53108736    start_time:06:00AM,end_time:11:59PM,start_day:SUNDAY
                start_time:06:00AM,end_time:11:59PM,start_day:MONDAY
```

I want to reorder the values of the output.
For eg: My output should be like

start_day:SUNDAY,start_time:06:00AM,end_time:11:59PM
start_day:MONDAY,start_time:06:00AM,end_time:11:59PM

Comment: Replied to a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67506717/15062605 . Do you think you can adapt it to your needs ?

Comment: Yes Cylldby it worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that! 